# What are the SMTP and POP settings for yahoo mail to use in outlook (in 2020)?

Tags: yahoo-mail, pop3, smtp

I have set up hundreds of email accounts in my life and do not understand what is going on with yahoo mail.

So first question - is yahoo free email still allowing the use of POP/SMTP services?   My outlook stopped attaching about 2 months ago and I have tried every port and setting possible to get it back and nothing.

Follow up, if it is supposed to work what are the correct settings.   Online it says smtp.mail.yahoo.com 465 and SSL (or 587/TLS) and pop.mail.yahoo.com 995/SSL...   I get really no error message just doesn't connect.   I have had these settings for years without an issue.   Tried changing passwords and many other iterations of ports/security.   No dice.

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. What do you mean by "Online it says..."? The source comes from Yahoo, Microsoft or somewhere else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yahoo announced changes to their security Ween using non-Yahoo applications (such as third-party email, calendar, or contact applications) that may use a less secure sign-in method.

They announced

> Yahoo will no longer support the current sign-in functionality in your
> application starting on 20 October 2020. This means that you will need
> to take one of the steps below to continue using Yahoo Mail without
> interruption.
>
> Option 1: We recommend that you access your email using our free Yahoo
> Mail app for iOS and Android or simply go to mail.yahoo.com to access
> Yahoo Mail on the web.
>
> Option 2: Keep your current, non-Yahoo app, BUT follow a few steps to
> get it to sync with our secure sign-in method. The steps vary across
> different email applications, but in most cases, you will have to
> remove your Yahoo account from the app and then add it back again to
> update the sign-in security. Use the links below to follow the
> specific steps for your current application:
>
> Option 3: You can generate a one-time, unique password that will allow
> you to sign in to your account using your non-Yahoo email application.
> Once created, this password will continue to allow your app to
> securely sync your Yahoo email unless you sign out (or are signed out)
> from your app.

Other than that you could try their [help page](https://en-global.help.yahoo.com/kb/new-mail-for-desktop/SLN27791.html?impressions=true)

Other than that, in answer to your direct question:

> What are the SMTP settings for yahoo mail

[image]

These settings from Mozilla Thunderbird email client.

**For Outlook Desktop:**

1. Go to [yahoo security page under your account](https://login.yahoo.com/account/security).
2. Scroll to bottom and generate password.
3. Choose outlook desktop.
4. It will put a password on the screen - 16 letters spaced out.
5. Use the "normal" outlook connection settings to yahoo.
6. Use this generated password minus the spaces in it.

Comment: thank you, edited it for outlook desktop.   Took me 30 seconds to do.   I have googled this issue and went through pages of examples and not once did I see something referencing generating app passwords.